# Cleanest way to search a 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The easiest way I could think of is a for loop:

```
var arr=[["hey","oh"],["scar","tissue"],["other","side"]];
var query="scar";
for(var z=0;z<arr.length;z++){
   if(arr[z].indexOf(query) !== -1){
      //Found
      break;
   }
}
```

Is there any other way to search for a string in a 2D array?

Comment: Are you able to sort alphabetically and run a binary search?

Comment: Sure! You could use a while loop, or recursion! But what's wrong with the method used in your question? What size arrays are we dealing with?

Comment: @Myles: o.O how? @Michael: The sizes aren't extreme, but that for loop is just to big to make a innocent search...so I'm thinking of making it simpler...

Comment: There is another way with jQuery or by prototyping the Array object. `$(arr).each(function(){if(this.indexOf(query)!=-1){/*it is*/}})`

Comment: +1 for being a RHCP fan!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var arr = [["hey","oh"],["scar","tissue"],["other","side"]];
var flat = [].concat.apply([], arr);
var col = flat.indexOf(query);
var row = -1;
if (col != -1) // found, now need to extract the row
  while (arr[++row].length <= col) // not this row
    col -= arr[row].length; // so adjust and try again
```

Comment: You could replace the while with a mod statement.

Comment: @tomdemuyt True, that works if the array is known to be rectangular.

Comment: @DavideVozzi Thanks for spotting my typo!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
var arr=[["hey","oh"],["scar","tissue"],["other","side"]];

arr.sort();
arr.join();
```

To sort alphabetically then,

A binary search works by looking at the middle value in the array then seeing if the searched for keyword/number is > or < that value and thus dividing the array in half, then splits the remaining in half again and continues until the searched value is found;

[image]

To implement a binary search please read here:
http://www.timlin.net/csm/cis111/Chapter10.pdf

Slides 52-56 on...

This method theoretically makes your search exponentially faster.

Comment: That works well for an array of numbers or strings, but not an array of arrays.

Comment: Surely if it is an array of arrays that makes it a 3D array and not 2D?

Comment: A 3D array is an array of array of array `[[[]]]`, so it's just a 2D one.